# Kotlin vert.x parsing a JSON String to a Data class using gson always returns null

Tags: kotlin, gson, vert.x

I am just playing around with vert.x 3.5.3 Kotlin and I am unable to parse a JSON string into a Data class using gson.

Here is the code

```java
class DataVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {
  override fun start(startFuture: Future<Void>) {

    data class Product(
      @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
      @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
      @SerializedName("productCode") val productCode: String
    )

    val products: MutableList<Product> = mutableListOf()
    val gson = Gson()

    val eventBus = vertx.eventBus()
    eventBus.consumer<String>("data.verticle") {
      when (it.headers().get("ACTION")) {
        "ADD_PRODUCT" -> {
          val prodJson = it.body()
          if (prodJson != null) {
            println(prodJson)
            val product = gson.fromJson(prodJson, Product::class.java)
            println(product)
            it.reply("SUCCESS")
          }
        }

        else -> {
          print("ERROR")
        }
      }
    }
    startFuture.complete()
  }
}
```

The Problem is the parsed value is always null 
Here is my sample json ->

```js
{"id":1,"name":"SOAP","productCode":"P101"}
```

The json string sent over the eventBus is not null. 
I am using this package for gson
com.google.code.gson', version: '2.8.5'

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare your class inside the method body, which Gson doesn't like much.

Extracting it to be nested class will work just fine:

class DataVerticle : AbstractVerticle() {
    override fun start(startFuture: Future) {
        val gson = Gson()

```
    val eventBus = vertx.eventBus()
    eventBus.consumer<String>("data.verticle") {
        when (it.headers().get("ACTION")) {
            "ADD_PRODUCT" -> {
                val prodJson = it.body()
                if (prodJson != null) {
                    println(prodJson)
                    val product = gson.fromJson(prodJson, Product::class.java)
                    println(product)
                    it.reply("SUCCESS")
                }
            }
            else -> {
                print("ERROR")
            }
        }
    }
    startFuture.complete()
}

data class Product(
    @SerializedName("id") val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("name") val name: String,
    @SerializedName("productCode") val productCode: String
)
```

}

Tested with:

```
val vertx = Vertx.vertx()

vertx.deployVerticle(DataVerticle()) {
    val options = DeliveryOptions()
    options.addHeader("ACTION", "ADD_PRODUCT")
    vertx.eventBus().send("data.verticle", """{"id":1,"name":"SOAP","productCode":"P101"}""", options)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, However I used another library called Kalxon to  Parse the JSON and it worked just fine. Is this a caveat specific to Gson?

Comment: I think it has to do with Gson being less aware of Kotlin features.